# winusb official product on multiboot usb

Tags: liveusb

Good day everyone! I wouldn't call myself a confident PC user and I'm trying to figure it out. I need to create a multiboot flash drive. Everyone writes about installing Winusb. How to find it? There is information here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/winusb-installation and a website for Winusb https://www.winusb.net/. Which one is the official product?

Comment: No, WinUSB is only for creating Windows installation media. It doesn't make multi-boot. You're looking for solutions like Ventoy, by far the easiest one and can be used as a normal mass storage device.